# iOS: A button in WebView doesn't appear

Tags: ios, angularjs, wkwebview

I've got a WKWebView in my project, which displays a certain web page. One of the page elements (a button) doesn't show. When I load the same page in the laptop browser everything's fine.

The button originally appears with a delay of 1-2 seconds and has an attribute of 'ng-show'.

What could possibly be a problem there?

Comment: How about iphone safari ? Can you try same website with safari from your iphone ? If same issue appears, than it's a web developer issue

Comment: Have you tried to debug the page in the webview using Safari on your computer?

Comment: @U.Benlice in iPhone Safari everything's fine. So it's not a web developer issue. What are other options? I broke my head already

Comment: @andlin Yes, I tried that but it's angular and I don't have access to all the attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't provide the detailed answer, because the issue was in the web part and was exclusive for this particular project. It was related to one of the header values of the `URLRequest` loaded by the `WKWebView`

Comment: Hi , any idea what you followed to figure this out? im having the exact same issue and it is blowing my mind